# Apache Spark: Building file/string in reduce function

Tags: scala, mapreduce, apache-spark

I am working with a set of quite big txt files, a couple of 100MB each. What I want to do is to copy those, whereat I map every line with a function `MapFunc`. See below my first try which is terribly slow. I am pretty sure the problem is with the reduce function, which concatenates this huge string.

The order how the lines are written to `outputFile` is not important, but they mustn't overlap. I already took a look at Spark's `saveAsTextFile` but as far as I understand I can't specify the filename, only the directory, which is not useful for my use case. Also, what about adding a header and footer and the comma between the elements of the RDD? I would be grateful for any advice how to tune this application to maximum performance.

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("MyApp")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val input = sc.textFile(file)
val lines = input.filter(s => filterFunc(s)).map(s => MapFunc(s))
val output = lines.reduce((a, b) => a + ',' + b)

val outputFile = new File(outFile)
val writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile))
val buf = new StringBuilder

buf ++= "header"
buf ++= output
buf ++= "footer"

writer.append(buf)
writer.flush()
writer.close()
```

Edit: My files are simple csv files. They can have comments (#). Also, I need to make sure that only files with 3 columns are processed, because the user is allowed to submit his own files for processing. This is done by `FilterFunc` which, to be honest, does not exclude whole files but only lines that do not match the criteria. A simple example would look like:

```
# File A
# generated mm/dd/yyyy
field11,field12,field13
field21,field22,field23
field31,field32,field33
```

And the output fill look like this:

```
$header
map(line1),
map(line2),
map(line3)
$footer
```

`saveAsTextFile` is really close to what I am looking for. But as already said it is important to me that I can control the filename and location of the output file.

Comment: Have a look at the `spark.csv` package from Databricks. I think that includes the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: Could you provide an example input/output? Do you really want a single line (plus  header/footer) for a whole RDD?

Comment: It would be so much better if you could explain the structure of files too -- fields, newlines etc.

Comment: I added information about the files. If the RDD elements in the output file are separated by newlines does not matter as long as there is a comma in between them. Spark-Csv looks nice, but the parsing itself is quite easy. It's the `MapFunction` which does the main job in my program.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a temporary buffer `buf`, you should consider writing directly to the file.

```
val writer = new PrintWriter(new File(outFile))
writer.print("header")
writer.print(output)
writer.print("footer")
writer.flush()
writer.close()
```

You can avoid concatenation, as well as consuming memory for `buf`.

Comment: A good hint, but I can't avoid concatenation completly. There is still the reduce function which is by far slower than this little bit of overhead introduced by the StringBuffer. I ran a test and the runtime does not change at all.